# Can anyone know if we can tag the MongoDB queries/commands to know which function of the app ran that query/command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using the same query (or slightly modified but using the same MongoDB Collection) in various functions and on Mongo Atlas, we get only the collection name and query but don't know which function actually triggered it.

Is there any way to tag the queries with the functions so it can be easy to debug?

Comment: why not just log the results after calling the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things come to mind.

The first is the ability to [apply a comment](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.comment/) to a query:

```
test> db.foo.find({x:123}).comment("unique identifier xyz");
test> db.system.profile.find().sort({ts:-1}).limit(1)
[
  {
    op: 'query',
    ns: 'test.foo',
    command: {
      find: 'foo',
      filter: { x: 123 },
      comment: 'unique identifier xyz',
      lsid: { id: UUID("6ce75fd2-dd4a-4c4e-9655-b80eca8ef755") },
      '$db': 'test'
    },
    keysExamined: 0,
    docsExamined: 10,
    ...
```

There is also the ability to apply [an `appName` in the connection string](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#miscellaneous-configuration).

---

Above I demonstrated [the database profiler](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) is one place where comments can show up, if configured. The full list of availability is described in the documentation.

For [comments](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.comment/#behavior):

> `comment()` associates a comment string with the find operation. This can make it easier to track a particular query in the following diagnostic outputs:
>
> - The `system.profile`
> - The `QUERY` log component
> - `db.currentOp()`
>
> See [configure log verbosity](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/log-messages/#std-label-log-messages-configure-verbosity) for the `mongod` log, the [Database Profiler tutorial](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/), or the [db.currentOp()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/#mongodb-method-db.currentOp) command.

And for [appName](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#mongodb-urioption-urioption.appName):

> Specify a custom app name. The app name appears in:
>
> - mongod and mongos logs
> - the currentOp.appName field in the currentOp command and db.currentOp() method output
> - the system.profile.appName field in the database profiler output
>
> The `appName` connection option is available for:
>
> - MongoDB Drivers starting in MongoDB 4.0
> - mongosh starting in mongosh 1.1.9
> - MongoDB Compass starting in Compass 1.28.4

Comment: Thanks for this. But you might need to enable the ProfilingLevel as well for your DB. 

db.setProfilingLevel(2)

Comment: Thanks - added details and links from the docs regarding availability  and configurability of each